# count of $lookup result mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

**Using mongodb with NodeJS driver**

I have 2 collections. One for department and other for students.

Sample data for Deparmtent.

```
{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId("5a24d20590d3d12155f3094e"), "name" : "CSE", "hod" : 
 "abc", 
 "students" : [ 
  ObjectId("5a2129172c3e542acb78c1f5"),
  ObjectId("5a2129172c3e542acb78c1f7"), 
  ObjectId("5a2129172c3e542acb78c1f9"), 
  ObjectId("5a2129172c3e542acb78c1fb")
 ]
}

{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5a24d20590d3d12155f3094f"), 
 "name" : "IT", 
 "hod" : "xyz", , 
 "students" : [ 
  ObjectId("5a2129172c3e542acb78c1f6"),
  ObjectId("5a2129172c3e542acb78c1f8"), 
  ObjectId("5a2129172c3e542acb78c1fa"),
  ObjectId("5a2129172c3e542acb78c1fc") 
 ] 
}
```

and sample data for Students

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a2129172c3e542acb78c1f4"),
    "rollNumber" : 11,
    "name" : "Thor",
    "branch" : ObjectId("5a24d20590d3d12155f3094e"),
}
```

Here is the query:

```
aggregate([
   {$lookup: 
     { from: "students", 
       localField: "_id", 
       foreignField: "branch",
       as: "studentData"
     }
   }
])
```

Output of the query

```
[ 
  { _id: 5a24d20590d3d12155f3094e,
    name: 'CSE',
    hod: 'abc',
    studentData: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] 
  },
  { _id: 5a24d20590d3d12155f3094f,
    name: 'IT',
    hod: 'xyz',
    studentData: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] } 
]
```

I have two questions

1. How to print complete student data.
2. How to get the count of studentData for each Department

Comment: Where you exactly want's to print data ?

Comment: You are printing complete student data, they are just in the form of an array. What is it exactly that you want?

Comment: @AlexP.  instead of "[Object]", I want, it to be in readable form

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**To get complete student data you can do something like**

```
db.student.aggregate(
        [
            {
            $lookup:
                {
                    from:"department",
                    localField:"branch",
                    foreignField:"_id",
                    as:"branch"
                }
            }
        ]
    )
```

This will give you something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : 1.0,
    "rollNumber" : 110.0,
    "name" : "Thor",
    "branch" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 1.0,
            "name" : "CSE",
            "hod" : "abc"
        }
    ]
}
```

**To get the count of studentData for each Department**

```
db.getCollection('student').aggregate(
    [
        {
        $lookup:
            {
                from:"department",
                localField:"branch",
                foreignField:"_id",
                as:"branch"
            }
        },
        {
            $group:
            {
                _id:"$branch",
                "numOfStudent":{$sum:1},
                "listOfStudents":{$push:"$name"}
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

This will give you something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 2.0,
            "name" : "IT",
            "hod" : "xyz"
        }
    ],
    "numOfStudent" : 1.0,
    "listOfStudents" : [ 
        "Ironman2"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 1.0,
            "name" : "CSE",
            "hod" : "abc"
        }
    ],
    "numOfStudent" : 3.0,
    "listOfStudents" : [ 
        "Thor", 
        "Ironman", 
        "Ironman3"
    ]
}
```

You can change `$push:$name` to `$push:$_id` If you want to store the Ids of students and not their names.

**EDIT**
Get similar result using "Departments" collection:

```
db.department.aggregate([
{
    $lookup:
                {
                    from:"student",
                    localField:"students",
                    foreignField:"_id",
                    as:"studentsDetails"
                }
},
{
    $project:{
            _id:0,
            name:"$name",
            hod:"$hod",
            numOfStudents:{$size:"$studentsDetails"},
            students:"$studentsDetails"
        }
}
])
```

This will give you something like this:

```
{
    "name" : "CSE",
    "hod" : "abc",
    "numOfStudents" : 2,
    "students" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 1.0,
            "rollNumber" : 110.0,
            "name" : "Thor",
            "branch" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 3.0,
            "rollNumber" : 111.0,
            "name" : "Ironman2",
            "branch" : 2.0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: your ans is giving the correct the result. Is there any way to get this reuslt when querrying from "Department" collection rather than "Students" ?

Comment: It can be done if you store a list of student Ids in department collection.

Comment: I tried but couldn't generate the answer. Saved students Ids in an array in "Departmnet collection". How to proceed further?

Comment: Can you update your question with new "Department collection"?

Comment: I have updated the answer. If that is what you were looking for, please mark the answer as correct! Thanks :)

Comment: You query looks awesome, but when the number of students is larger, the query is throwing the exception: "Total size of documents in student matching ..... exceeds maximum document size"

Comment: Thanks for the ansewrs, saved me few hours of testing

Comment: @AnirudhBagri, Can we get numOfStudentsInBranch1, numOfStudentisInBranch2, with single query ?

Answer (score 23):

Your $lookup is completely fine. To add a count of students to your output data, you can use $addFields.

Add this to your aggregation:

```
{ $addFields: {studentCount: {$size: "$studentData"}}}
```

}

So, your query should be something like this:

```
aggregate([
   {$lookup: 
     { from: "students", 
       localField: "_id", 
       foreignField: "branch", as: "studentData"
     }
   }, { $addFields: {studentCount: {$size: "$studentData"}}
}
])
```