# Aggregation of different collections in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Not sure how to do this, have a background in SQL and it is quite easier there to achieve what I need to do.

Basically I have the collection news which is like this:

```
const news = [
{id: '123123123', category: [ObjectID(12312312323), ObjectID(987987987)]},
{id: '123123123', category: []},
{id: '123123123', category: [ObjectID(987987987)]}
]
```

and then I have the collection category which is like this:

```
const category = [
{name: "123a", _id: ObjectID(123123123}, title:"blah blah" },
{name: "987a", _id: ObjectID(987987987}, title:"blih blah" ,
]
```

what I need to do is to join both tables and get an aggregation like

```
[
{name: "987a", title: "blih blah", count: 2},
{name: "123a", title: "blah blah", count: 1}
 
]
```

So even in MySQL I would get this like something similar to:

```
SELECT name, title, count(Select count(category) from news) from categories
```

But I am not getting it with mongoDb / mongoose.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [count of $lookup result mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47627701/count-of-lookup-result-mongodb)

Comment: No,It is not really what I need. I need to count the occurrences of the ID inside the array of categories, and not to do a Inner join otherwise the query becomes slow. Ps: that answer should be revised…

Comment: you can't use populate to get size, you have to use aggregate method, see my answer.

Comment: yap you were right. I was querying the wrong collection. Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$lookup` to join `news` collection, pass `_id` as localField and `category` as foreignField
- `$size` to get total element `count` of new collection result

```
db.category.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "news",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "category",
      as: "count"
    }
  },
  { $set: { count: { $size: "$count" } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3qkX2Xr6AB_)